# Can I check all the values in a dictionary at once?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

Looking at my code...

```
# 1 = in the bookshelf, 0 = not in the bookshelf
bookshelf = {}
bookshelf["The Incredible Book About Pillows"] = 1
bookshelf["Little Fox and his Friends"] = 1
bookshelf["How To Become a Superhero: Part 1"] = 0

if bookshelf["The Incredible Book About Pillows"] == 1:
    print("The Incredible Book about Pillows")
if bookshelf["Little Fox and his Friends"] == 1:
    print("Little Fox and his Friends")
if bookshelf["How To Become a Superhero: Part 1"] == 1:
    print("How To Become a Superhero: Part 1")
```

...is there any better way to print all the books that are currently in the bookshelf (has value 1)? Or is the easiest way to simply just delete them from the dictionary when I take them out of the bookshelf and add them when I put them back?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a dictionary's items fairly easily like so:

```
for key, value in bookshelf.items():   #.iteritems() also works, returns an iterator.
  if value == 1:
    print key
```

`.items()` will return a list of `(key, value)` tuples for you to peruse and check.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
booksInShelf = [book for book in bookshelf if bookshelf[book] == 1]
for book in booksInShelf:
    print(book)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) You can use the keys property of the dictionary to see if the key (book title) is currently contained in the dictionary. The [dict documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) has lots more useful information.

2) You can use a list comprehension to filter your list into another list that just contains book titles that "== 1"

Comment: I'm a noob, so I didn't really understand all that... can you explain a bit more thoroughly?

Comment: The explanation (and direction you want to go) depends a lot on what you're trying to do with your dictionary. Are you just keeping a list of books that you have? If that's the case then a list would probably be a better construct than a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
for book in bookshelf.keys():
    if bookshelf[book] == 1:
        print book
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda k: k if bookshelf[k] == 1 else None, bookshelf)
```